# facebook fbml application confused

Tags: php, facebook

I'm newbie in creating application on facebook

My app type is FBML,

Why cant i use

```
<fb:share-button href="http://apps.facebook.com/example" type="box_count"></fb:share-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons:

1. You haven't loaded and initialized the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
2. You haven't included the FBML namespace:

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
3. Your application isn't correctly set up for your domain. Make sure your application settings are correct in your Developer Application.

Those are the only reasons I can think of. Just so you know, [Facebook recommends that new developers do not use FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the XFBML version of the tag in a native FBML environment.

Omit the closing tag and you should be good.

```
<fb:share-button href="http://apps.facebook.com/example" type="box_count" />
```